# Suppress closed branches in hg view

Tags: mercurial, branch, dvcs

Is there a way to prevent closed branches from showing up *at the top* when running the hg view command?  I know about the 'limit' option.  I don't really need closed branches to completely disappear from the view, but it would be nice if they would stay down (they were closed long ago), rather than popping up near the top every time I perform a merge.

[image: hg view with a closed branch near current development]

Here is an example screenshot where this happens. You can see on the right that the times are all mixed up, which isn't too terrible in this case, but in my real repo the closed-off branches pop up near the top everytime I have a merge, which gets annoying when the closed-off branch is well over a year ago and truly not interesting.

Comment: What is `hg view`? I am not familiar with that command.

Comment: @Lasse: You have to enable the hgk extension (which is built-in to hg) to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody has updated `hg view` to be aware of closed branches. The extension is mostly abandoned these days since none of the core developers use it or know how to program in Tcl/Tk. We talk about removing hgk at every major release...

Your best bet is to upgrade to [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) and use the command `hgtk log` to view the repository.

The best thing is that it works on both Windows **and** Linux -- see the [`hgtk` wiki page](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/hgtk/wiki/hgtk). In `hgtk` you can filter using the new [revision sets](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets/) syntax. This revset query will find open changesets:

```
ancestors(head() and not closed())
```

Answer (score 1):

The program [hgview](http://www.logilab.org/project/hgview/) doesn't show the dead branches at the top and is available in Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I just gave this a go, and it does sidestep the questioners problem.  But at least when running through an X-server on a Windows client, it is really slow (compared to either the `hg view` command, or the tortoise workbench).